# Intermittent issues with Envoy and SSH in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, phpseclib

I've been playing with the SSH remote component and Envoy in Laravel 4.1 recently and i've had issues with both. We have 10+ servers which i'm looking at deploying updates to via either Envoy or the SSH component in Laravel.

First the SSH - I've set this up within `app/config/remote.php` and declared the servers as a group. As a test I want to loop through each server and just return the hostname to make sure they're all connecting ok. I can do this with this in my `app/routes.php`

```
Route::get('/test', function(){

    $commands = array(
        'hostname'
    );

    $servers = Config::get('remote.groups.servers');

    foreach($servers as $server){
        SSH::into($server)->run($commands,function($output){
            echo $output.PHP_EOL;
        });
    }

});
```

however, for every 2 or 3 times I run this script I get an error, there's no pattern though in terms of which server errors and it doesn't happen every time - sometimes it works fine.

The error I get is:

> Cannot connect to 192.168.0.1:8899. Banner timeout

(where 192.168.0.1 is my server IP)

So, i've got an intermittent issue but its enough to mean I cannot rely on this feature for reliable deployments unless I fix it. I've looked into the error a bit and it's coming from **phpseclib** but most mentions i've seen seem to imply this has been fixed. But, where I get confused here is who if anyone I should be reporting this error to. Is it an issue with phpseclib, or an issue with Laravel, or an issue with my servers or an issue with my local machine (new rMPB running Mavericks but also seen on vagrant box running CentOS 6.4).

I decided after this to check out Envoy to see if that would work better. In short though, I have a similar issue. I'm not sure exactly what the issue is as Envoy just seems to fail silently without any error being displayed but a similar script running on envoy (just to return the output of something basic like "ls -l" or "hostname") also sometimes works and sometimes fails - to the extent I have to CTRL+C the command to stop it.

I assume that beneath the hood Envoy is using the same SSH code so the issue belongs to both.

Has anyone else seen these issues and can anyone recommend how I can get it resolved?

**EDIT**

Following this through the error is thrown here in `SSH2.php` (within phpseclib)

```
if (!@stream_select($read, $write, $except, $sec, $usec) && !count($read)) {           
      user_error(rtrim("Cannot connect to $host. Banner timeout"));
      return false
 }
```

It seems that for some reason `$read` will be empty after this issue has occurred - it has a value before the stream_select is called but is empty afterwards. Following a successful call the value is retained. Not sure what that means though!

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the execution is taking to long. Split the process or increase time before timeout.

Comment: Any ideas how I could debug if this is the case or not?

Comment: Could you comment out the stream_select and see what happens? I'm wondering if maybe your PHP installation is having stream_select issues.

Comment: i've tried that @neubert and it just hangs

Comment: Sounds like it's probably a problem with the SSH server then. Can you connect with any other client? What about from the same IP as laravel / envoy / phpseclib is connecting from?

Comment: I can connect just fine with terminal using the same public key, as I said though the issue isn't always happening and doesn't always happen on the same server. Is there anything I should be checking on the remote server to debug other that /var/log/secure?

Comment: I guess you could check to make sure that LogLevel in /etc/ssh/sshd_config is set to DEBUG3 and then do `sudo service ssh restart` or something like that. Maybe check /var/log/auth.log as well idk.